# How to configure Memcache for Django on Google cloud AppEngine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, memcached

In my settings i have:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

and i have installed
https://pypi.org/project/python-memcached/

Anything else needed?

Answer (score 2):

The way to enable Memcache for Django on GCP depends on which product you are using (App Engine, Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine) [1]

Since you are using App Engine, it is built-in.  You can find examples on how to use Memcache with GCP here. [2]

[1] How to install Memcache on GCP for Django:
 https://cloud.google.com/python/django/#caches

[2]Memcache examples on GCP Docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/examples?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone who's trying to do this in 2023: the accepted answer is a good start, but is incomplete. There are a number of inconsistencies between the [`google.appengine.api.memcache`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache) interface and the [`django.core.cache.backends.memcached.BaseMemcachedCache`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py) interface that need to be resolved.

I am using Django 3.2 in a Google App Engine Python 3.10 runtime.

The most important inconsistencies for my use case were

1. GAE's `memcache.get` does not support `BaseMemcachedCache.get`'s `default` parameter. This results in a mystifying `TypeError: Cannot set google.appengine.MemcacheGetRequest.name_space` error.
2. Google's `memcache.incr` and `memcache.decr` support an `initial_value` parameter which is not supported by `BaseMemcachedCache.incr/decr`.
3. An important corollary to (1) is that GAE's `memcache` does not support the default object pattern for disambiguating cache misses from legitimately cached `None` values.

The implementation below resolves these inconsistencies for my use case. I'm sure there are other inconsistencies between GAE's `memcache` API and `BaseMemcachedCache`, but they're not currently relevant to my use case. Feel free to use this as a starting point for your own implementation.

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache

from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.core.cache.backends.base import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
from django.core.cache.backends.memcached import BaseMemcachedCache


class GaeMemcachedCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
    def __init__(self, server, params):
        super().__init__(server, params, library=memcache, value_not_found_exception=ValueError)

    def decr(self, key, delta=1, version=None, initial_value=None):
        if delta < 0:
            return self.incr(key, delta=-delta, version=version, initial_value=initial_value)

        key = self.make_key(key, version=version)
        self.validate_key(key)

        value = self._cache.decr(key, delta=delta, initial_value=initial_value)

        if value is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Key '{key}' not found")

        return value

    def get(self, key, default=None, version=None):
        if not self.has_key(key, version=version):
            return default

        key = self.make_key(key, version=version)
        self.validate_key(key)

        return self._cache.get(key)

    def has_key(self, key, version=None):
        """
        Returns `True` if a key is present in the cache, otherwise `False`.

        `google.appengine.api.memcache.get` doesn't support a `default` argument. Instead, it
        returns `None` for a cache miss. `replace()`, however, returns False if the intended
        key isn't present in the cache. We can therefore check to see if key is present by
        `get`ing it and then replacing it with itself.

        `google.appengine.api.memcache` also doesn't support a way to determine a key's
        expiration time, so this approach results in the loss of that information, but
        only for keys whose value was positively set to `None`.
        """
        key = self.make_key(key, version=version)
        self.validate_key(key)

        value = self._cache.get(key)

        if value is None:
            return self._cache.replace(key, value)

        return True

    def incr(self, key, delta=1, version=None, initial_value=None):
        if delta < 0:
            return self.decr(key, delta=-delta, version=version, initial_value=initial_value)

        key = self.make_key(key, version=version)
        self.validate_key(key)

        value = self._cache.incr(key, delta=delta, initial_value=initial_value)

        if value is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Key '{key}' not found")

        return value

    @cached_property
    def _cache(self):
        if getattr(self, '_client', None) is None:
            self._client = self._lib._CLIENT
        return self._client
```